# I need to change the format of 'date' from yyyy-dd-mm to mm-dd-yyyy

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, date-format

My dilema,

I was requested to populate a table of sample data and I completed the command to add a date.

I entered '07-07-2016' as sample data. When running a query the "date_ordered" field came back as "0000-00-00".

I need to convert the already stored data to the MM-DD-YYYY format. I would prefer to convert the data completely, not just the view.

Thanks

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using and version'

Comment: Are you storing dates as varchar(string/text) type or date type... If 1., you should not store date as string (whichever RDBMS is used).

Comment: I have the data set to 'date'. Which is why the return data is completely different than what I entered. If I would have stored it as a string, it would have came back as how I entered it.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Insert into 'order_info' (order_date);

Comment: You wrote: "Which is why the return data is completely different than what I entered. If I would have stored it as a string, it would have came back as how I entered it". Storing `DATE`s as VARCHARs is a **very bad** idea. There is a bit of fiddling with formatting but soon becomes second nature. The **main** thing is that it confuses the optimizer and could slow your system. Plus, datetime functions won't work with strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your column date_ordered is of type DATE, MySQL will store it in its own way. To display it in the format you want, you should use the function date_format():

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

e.g. For DD-MM-YYYY format, you want to use the format string '%d-%m-%Y'

> select date_format (date_ordered,'%d-%m-%Y') from your_table;

If you want to store the date in that format, use a VARCHAR instead of a DATE type, but then you will have to typecast the string to a date before performing any other date-based functions on it. Better to let MySQL store the date how it wants, and convert it to the desired format when displaying.